# Passing an argument from terminal to python file

Tags: python-3.8

So i have a file named:

**helloName.py**

It has the following code below:

```
def hello(name,age):
print('Hello ' + name + '. How are you today?' )
print ('You are', age ,'years old.'  )
```

from terminal I would like to type **helloName.py eric, 35** to run the script.

The result should be:

```
Hello Eric. How are you today?
You are 35 years old.
```

When I do it now it does nothing.  No error or anything.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get input first and execute function after that. Edit your file like below...

```
import sys
def hello(name,age):
    print('Hello ' + name + '. How are you today?' )
    print ('You are', age ,'years old.'  )

name = sys.argv[1]
age = sys.argv[2]

hello(name, age)
```

Then type in terminal `python3 <file_name>.py arg1 arg2`. Arguments are `arg1=Name` and `arg2=Age`

Comment: with the the input, it is waiting for input.  Thats not what I am looking for.  I want it to get its values from the command line.